# Entity framework issue mapping dateTime attribute (table with indexes)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I've created my Table by this way

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FULL](
[event_handle] [int] NOT NULL,
[mc_host] [varchar](128) NULL,
[date_reception] [datetime] NULL)
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [event_handle] ASC
)
```

Than i added an index to mc_host and date_reception so as to make query faster

```
create index i_host
on [FULL](mc_host)
where (date_reception > '2014-01-01')

create index i_date_reception
on [FULL](date_reception)
where (date_reception > '2014-01-01')
```

In my model i have the following code

```
   public partial class full
{
public int event_handle { get; set; }
    public string host { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> date_reception { get; set; }

}
```

The probleme is with the date_reception attribute, when i call
this query

```
   var myList = (from p in db.full
                      where (p.date_reception > new DateTime(2015, 01, 01)
                      group p by p.mc_object into g
                      orderby g.Count() descending
                      select new StringIntType
                      {
                          str = g.Key,

                      }).ToList();
```

all works fine , but when i declare date_reception value outside query that way.

```
  DateTime dt = new DateTime(2015, 01, 01);
        var myList = (from p in db.full
                      where (p.date_reception > dt )
                      group p by p.mc_object into g
                      orderby g.Count() descending
                      select new StringIntType
                      {
                          str = g.Key,

                      }).ToList();
```

I get `An error occurred during the execution`.Please i need to know why.

Comment: Does an error occur when you make *dt* nullable?

Comment: Can you execute the query without the group by and order by? If this succeeds, can you add group by and order by one by one. Maybe you'll get a more prescriptive error this way. And we know when the error exactly occurs.